# How does C++ implicitly cast arguments to a comparator such as <?

Tags: c++, casting, comparator, implicit-conversion

I had thought that this would be an easy question resolve via Google, but I can't seem to find a definitive (or even speculative) answer:

When using a comparator statement, in which order does implicit casting occur?

```
int i = -1;
size_t t = 1;

bool result = i < t;
```

Is this equivalent to:

```
bool result = i < int(t);    // equals true
```

or:

```
bool result = size_t(i) < t;    // equals false
```

That is the easy part of the question - the second part is "what is the general rule", as it could be:

1. The 'simpler' argument is always converted into the 'more complex' argument (i.e. size_t->int), or
2. The first (or second) argument is always converted to the type of the second (or first) argument, or
3. The inbuilt primitives such as size_t and ints have specific comparator operators which specify the casting case-by-case.

All three seem reasonable, although the second would yield significantly different behaviour to what most people would intuitively expect.

The VC++ compiler seems to think it's worth a level 3 warning when you compare an int with a size_t - and yet it only gives a level 4 warning when you return a negative number from a function that returns a size_t (which results in a number just over half the maximum integer being returned).

In an effort to get rid of all level 4 warnings, I now explicitly cast everything anyway, but I wanted to know "the truth".  This must be defined somewhere...

Comment: In no way. A cast, by definition, is explicit. Implicit type conversion is called "coertion".

Comment: These conversions are defined in Clause 4 of the C++ standard.

Comment: 4 Standard conversions: pag77 and 4.5 Integral promotions pag79 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf

Comment: Ah, excellent - I was going to ask where th C++ standard was actually defined!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rules are fairly complex, and depend on the implementation.
Basically, however:

1. Both types are "promoted".  This means that anything
   smaller than `int` is promoted to `int`.  (In the unlikely case
   that `size_t` is smaller than `int`, it will be promoted to
   a signed `int`, and loose its unsignedness.)
2. If one of the types can contain all of the values of the
   other, the other is converted to this type.
3. If one of the types is unsigned, and the other signed, and
   they have the same size, the signed is converted to the
   unsigned.

For `int` and `size_t` (which is required to be unsigned), this
means that unless `size_t` is smaller than `int`, the `int` will
be converted to a `size_t`.

Comment: +1 see also this [Channel 9 episode](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-7-of-n) by Stephan T. Lavavej

Comment: Thanks, @JamesKanze.  So this is probably what most people would expect/want - that is good.  I guess there is a theoretical risk if an unsigned int which is over half its maximum size is converted to a signed int, the bit which is used for the signage will compete with one of the binary-bits required to represent the number.  This would be pretty unusual, however.  Any idea why VC++ regards this as a level 3 issue?

Comment: @MikeSadler Conversions between signed and unsigned of the same size do result in surprises, e.g. `ui < -1` will almost always be true.  In general, I avoid unsigned types for this reason---the "polute" expressions.

Answer (score 4):

> $18.2/6- The type size_t is an implementation-defined **unsigned integer**
>   type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object.
>
> $5.9 - Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has
>   rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other
>   operand, **the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.** For the first
>   part, bool is promoted to an int, before the conversion as specified
>   by the C++ standard.

So, this means that 'i' is converted to the type of 'size_t' (assuming size_t is of type 'unsigned int' or greater). Then the results which is of type 'unsigned int' is converted to 'bool' (which is the type of `result`).

Note that the Standard specifies that the rank of `signed int` and `unsigned int` the same.

Refer Section 4 and 5 of the C++ standard for the exact rules for conversions/promotions.

Comment: Thanks, @Chubsdad.  I must say I find it difficult to fully understand these standards - like legal English.  Does $5.9 mean that worst case I described in my question could be realised?  Could a signed int be coerced (thanks @H2CO3) into an unsigned int of radically different magnitude and then compared incorrectly (or at least unexpectedly) with the other unsigned int?