# Are C macros implicitly cast?

Tags: c++, c, macros, types, c-preprocessor

I've searched SO, but haven't found an answer to this specific questions. Forgive me if it's already been answered.

If you have the following:

```
#define MACRO  40
```

You don't assign it to a variable you use it in a loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MACRO; i++) {...
```

The perprocessor then creates:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {...
```

Would the compiler then implicitly cast it to an int since the comparison is with type `int i`?  I've looked at this question [Type of #define variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584383/type-of-define-variables), and quite a few answers down Edgar Bonet implies that there is an order in which the compiler chooses how to treat the macro?

This question, [How does C++ implicitly cast arguments to a comparator such as  <?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14603882/how-does-c-implicitly-cast-arguments-to-a-comparator-such-as), was also suggested, but only describes how implicit casting works with a comparison with two types.  Since a macro doesn't really have a type I'm not sure if this applies.

Comment: `40` is already an `int`.

Comment: A C macro is just a text replace.

Comment: C macros are simply text replacement. It behaves just as if you'd typed `40` there.

Comment: The compiler proper has no clue at all that that `40` came from a macro. The compiler proper analyses the code after the pre-compiler has done its substitutions.

Comment: A macro doesn't have type, but the replacement text, but `40` does.  Once the macro is expanded, it behaves exactly as if you had typed the text/.

Comment: without suffix a number without decimal point is **always** an int, just like a floating-point number will always be double unless appended by an `f` or `L` suffix. If you need wider int types, use `U` or `L` suffix

Comment: @chris well it is not an `int` until phase `7`. There is a bit of details going from a macro to `40` having a type. It is a bit disappointing most answers choose to glaze over most of them.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, How did I know someone would find a way to pedantically prove me wrong? :)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I mean in int's range. Over that range it will have the next type in the list. Forgot to say that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) expands macros before the compiler even sees anything. We can see that preprocessing numbers don't have a type by going to the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) section `6.4.8` *Preprocessing numbers* which says:

> A preprocessing number does not have type or a value; it acquires both
>   after a successful conversion (as part of translation phase 7) to a
>   floating constant token or an integer constant token.

The same section in the draft C++ standard is `2.10`.

As we can see in [C preprocessor Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) macro expansion happens in phase 4.

The conversion of integer constants in C terminology and integer literals in C++ terminology is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.4.4.1` *Integer constants* and the following table in paragraph *5* which says:

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list
>   in which its value can be represented

```
                                           Octal or Hexadecimal
Suffix        Decimal Constant                 Constant
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
none          int                           int
              long int                      unsigned int
              long long int                 long int                                
                                            unsigned long int
                                            long long int
                                            unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
u or U        unsigned int                  unsigned int
              unsigned long int             unsigned long int
              unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
l or L        long int                      long int
              long long int                 unsigned long int
                                            long long int
                                            unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Both u or U   unsigned long int             unsigned long int
and  l or L   unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ll or LL      long long int                 long long int
                                            unsigend long long int
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Both u or U   unsigned long long int        unsigned long long int
and  ll or LL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Table is a modified version of the one from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21383314/1708801). The section that covers this in the draft C++ standard is section `2.14.2` which also has a similar table.

So in your example `40` has no suffix and is a decimal constant and the first type it can be represented from that section of the table is *int*.

At this point we now end up with the effects of using `40` with the `<` operator. Since `i` and `40` are both *arithmetic types* then the  usual arithmetic conversions will be performed, which in this case will still be *int*. For *C99* this is covered in section `6.3.1.8` and C++ section *5*.

Comment: Thanks!  That's exactly the type of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

In C and C++, macros are quite literally in-place replacement. The preprocessor will encounter these `#define`s and replace them as it finds them. That's how you can nest macros inside of macros and it only takes 1 pass to preprocess.

Answer (score 5):

C macros are simply textual replacements, they have no types. Everything involving types is done *after* the macro substitution, and acts the same as if you'd typed the replacement in the original code.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler never sees the macro; the preprocessor expands all macros before the source text is fed into the compiler.

All the *compiler* sees is

```
for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {...}
```

and the type of the constant expression `40` is determined based on the rules in section 6.4.4.1 of the [2011 C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) or section 2.13 of the [online C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In *C* macros are just replacement text that means that the text the macro represents is copied instead of the macro name, you can put even *C* keywords in macro.

```
#define [identifier name] [value]
```

In the code the *identifier name* is replace by the *value*. Your definition was:

```
#define MACRO  40
```

`40` is already an int.
so `for(int i = 0; i < 40; i++)` no cast is required.