# What is the proper way to store narrower data types into a wider data type in the C language?

Tags: c, types

I'm currently fixing a legacy bug in C code. In the process of fixing this bug, I stored an `unsigned int` into an `unsigned long long`. But to my surprise, math stopped working when I compiled this code on a 64 bit version of `GCC`. I discovered that the problem was that when I assigned a `long long` an int value, then I got a number that looked like `0x0000000012345678`, but on the 64-bit machine, that number became `0xFFFFFFFF12345678`.

Can someone explain to me or point me to some sort of spec or documentation on what is supposed to happen when storing a smaller data type in a larger one and perhaps what the appropriate pattern for doing this in C is?

**Update - Code Sample**

Here's what I'm doing:

```
// Results in 0xFFFFFFFFC0000000 in 64 bit gcc 4.1.2
// Results in 0x00000000C0000000 in 32 bit gcc 3.4.6
u_long foo = 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: How are you storing the value? If you did something like `int64_t my64bitInt = (int64_t)some32bitInt`, then this should not happen. Are you using `memcpy` or some block-based copy mechanism, or are you doing direct assignment like in my first example above? There are ways to accomplish this by using block-based copying rather than direct assignment. In C, up-casting is implicit and guarantee harmless, unless you are converting between fixed and floating point values.

Comment: *Unsigned long long* can represent all values of *unsigned int*, hence what you describe is not possible. So the key part of the question is *how* you do "assign" operation :)

Comment: Added code sample. The sample uses an int constant, but this also happens if the int is a variable.

Comment: What type is `u_long`? Is it a typedef for `unsigned long`?

Comment: It comes from sys/types.h It is an unsigned long.

Comment: `u_long foo = 3UL * 1024UL * 1024UL * 1024UL;`

Comment: @indiv maybe should be `3UL * 1024UL ...`?

Comment: @clcto:  Yeah, that would be appropriate in this case, thanks.

Comment: To be portable, it would be better to use `unsigned long long` rather than `unsigned long`. A `long` is only 32 bits long on some 64 bit machines. The standard guarantees that `long long` is at least 64 bits.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you have to tell the compiler that the number on the right is unsigned. Otherwise it thinks it's a normal signed int, and since the sign bit is set, it thinks it's negative, and then it sign-extends it into the receiver.

So do some unsigned casting on the right.

Comment: That's it exactly. 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 overflows the size of a signed int. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Signedness is not the only issue.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: In this particular case, the mathematical result of `3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` happens to fit in an `unsigned int` but not in an `int` (assuming 32-bit `int`). More generally, if the expression overflows, making the operands unsigned doesn't always help (the behavior can be well defined but it can still wrap around). Consider `unsigned long long foo = 1024U * 1024U * 1024U * 1024U;` The mathematical result is 2**40, which fits in an `unsigned long long` but not in an `unsigned long`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I do not think it is if the _product_ fits in an `int` or `unsigned` that is driving the issue.  Each of the numbers `3`, `1024`, `1024`, `1024`  fit in an `int`, so therefore the result is based on `int` * `int` * `int` * `int` which is an `int` which is then assigned to a `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @chux: I'm not sure what you mean. All the operands are of type `int`, so all three multiplications are done in type `int`; if `INT_MAX < 2147483648`, it will overflow *before* the conversion to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I was addressing "mathematical result of 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 happens to fit in an unsigned int ...".  It appears to imply the mathematical product of 3,221,225,472 determined the type.  Your additional comment, matches my understanding that the type of the result `3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` is an `int` because that is the C result of  `int` * `int` * `int` * `int`.

Comment: @chux: Ah, I see. My point was that casting the leftmost operand to `unsigned` only happens to work in this case because the mathematical result of `3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` happens to fit in a 32-bit `unsigned`. Given `(unsigned)3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`, all the `int` operands are converted to `unsigned int` (not because of the values, but because of their types). But in the most general case, that's not enough; instead, you should convert to the target type (`u_long` in this case -- whatever that is).

Answer (score 13):

Expressions are generally evaluated independently; their results are not affected by the context in which they appear.

An integer constant like `1024` is of the smallest of `int`, `long int`, `long long int` into which its value will fit; in the particular case of `1024` that's always `int`.

I'll assume here that `u_long` is a typedef for `unsigned long` (though you also mentioned `long long` in your question).

So given:

```
unsigned long foo = 3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

the 4 constants in the initialization expression are all of type `int`, and all three multiplications are `int`-by-`int`. The result happens to be greater (by a factor of 1.5) than 2<sup>31</sup>, which means it won't fit in an `int` on a system where `int` is 32 bits. The `int` result, whatever it is, will be implicitly converted to the target type `unsigned long`, but by that time it's too late; the overflow has already occurred.

The overflow means that your code has undefined behavior (and since this can be determined at compile time, I'd expect your compiler to warn about it). In practice, signed overflow typically wraps around, so the above will *typically* set `foo` to `-1073741824`. You can't count on that (and it's not what you want anyway).

The ideal solution is to avoid the implicit conversions by ensuring that everything is of the target type in the first place:

```
unsigned long foo = 3UL * 1024UL * 1024UL * 1024UL;
```

(Strictly speaking only the first operand needs to be of type `unsigned long`, but it's simpler to be consistent.)

Let's look at the more general case:

```
int a, b, c, d; /* assume these are initialized */
unsigned long foo = a * b * c * d;
```

You can't add a `UL` suffix to a variable. If possible, you should change the declarations of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` so they're of type `unsigned long long`, but perhaps there's some other reason they need to be of type `int`. You can add casts to *explicitly* convert each one to the correct type. By using casts, you can control exactly when the conversions are performed:

```
unsigned long foo = (unsigned long)a *
                    (unsigned long)b *
                    (unsigned long)d *
                    (unsigned long)d;
```

This gets a bit verbose; you might consider applying the cast only to the leftmost operand (after making sure you understand how the expression is parsed).

NOTE: This will *not* work:

```
unsigned long foo = (unsigned long)(a * b * c * d);
```

The cast converts the `int` result to `unsigned long`, but only after the overflow has already occurred. It merely specifies explicitly the cast that would have been performed implicitly.

Answer (score 4):

Integral literals with a suffix are *int* if they can fit, in your case `3` and `1024` can definitely fit. This is covered in the draft C99 standard section `6.4.4.1` *Integer constants*, a quote of this section can be found in my answer to [Are C macros implicitly cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148306/1708801).

Next we have the multiplication, which performs the *usual arithmetic conversions* conversions on it's operands but since they are all *int* the result of which is too large to fit in a signed int which results in overflow. This is undefined behavior as per section *5* which says:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an expression (that is, if the
>   result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its
>   type), the behavior is undefined.

We can discover this undefined behavior  empirically using clang and the `-fsanitize=undefined` flags (*[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8abe27c2fe568e1b)*) which says:

> runtime error: signed integer overflow: 3145728 * 1024 cannot be represented in type 'int'

Although in two complement this will just end up being a negative number. One way to fix this would be to use the `ul` suffix:

```
3ul * 1024ul * 1024ul * 1024ul
```

So why does a negative number converted to an unsigned value give a very large unsigned value? This is covered in section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers* which says:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.49)

which basically means `unsigned long max + 1` is added to the negative number which results in very large unsigned value.