# Constant integer promotion rules?

Tags: c++, c++11

To give a little background (unrelated to the question, which will follow), in C++11 I noticed a narrowing issue:

```
int foo[] = { 0xFFFFFFFF };
```

This was failing to compile (narrowing conversion) because `0xFFFFFFFF` is an `unsigned int`. However, I've seen cases where `0xFF` is signed.

I've looked over integer promotion rules, but this is mostly within the context of lvalues and not rvalues/constants. How does the compiler determine the type of constants (without literal suffixes)? Is there documentation or a nice little table / "cheat sheet" that shows the rules for this? I'm not even really sure what this is called, otherwise I'd have attempted to find it myself in the C++11 standard.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the narrowest type needed with signed being prioritized and a minimum of `int`.

Comment: I added several extra details to my answer that you may find useful/interesting.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a table in the standard, which is reproduced on cppreference.com: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

In particular, a hex or octal integer literal with no suffix is considered to have the first type in the following list in which its value can be represented:

```
int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int
```

`0xFFFFFFFF` is too big for `int` if `int` is 32 bits long, so `unsigned int` is chosen. But `0xFF` fits comfortably into an `int`, so `int` it is.

Comment: So then it's safe to say it looks at integral ranges, and not specifically its bit depth. That helps make things crystal clear, if so.

Comment: @RobertDailey That's right, yeah, it doesn't directly depend on the number of bits, although obviously it does indirectly.

Answer (score 7):

What are called referred to as *Integer constants* in C are referred to as *integer literals* in C++. The rules used to determine the type of an *integer literal* are covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `2.14.2` *Integer literals* table `6` which says:

> The type of an integer literal is the first of the corresponding list
>   in Table 6 in which its value can be represented.

and for *Octal or hexadecimal constant* with no suffix the table has the following order:

> ```
> int
> unsigned int
> long int
> unsigned long int
> long long int
> unsigned long long int
> ```

So `0xFF` can be represented as an *int* while the first type that can represent `0xFFFFFFFF` would be *unsigned int*.

The order for *Decimal Constants* is as follows:

> ```
> int
> long int
> long long int
> ```

As we can see hexidecimal and octal literals behave differently, and we can see [that C99 has the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148306/1708801). The  [Rationale for International Standard—Programming Languages—C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) says the following about this:

> Unlike decimal constants, octal and hexadecimal constants too large to
>   be ints are typed as unsigned int if within range of that type, since
>   it is more likely that they represent bit patterns or masks, which are
>   generally best treated as unsigned, rather than “real” numbers.

[cppreference integer literal section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) also quotes table `6` in the *The type of the literal* sub-section.

Comment: +1 for quoting standard and also telling me what this concept is named.

Comment: basically, if you want to use signed integer you should just use `int foo[] = {-1};`

Answer (score 2):

`0xFF` is never negative. It is an alternative way of writing `255`. (It has type `int`).

`0xFFFFFFFF` is a large positive number. There is a table under [lex.icon] that specifies what the type is of an integer constant. For hex constants with no suffix, it is the first type in the following list that can hold that large positive number: `int`, `unsigned int`, `long int`, `unsigned long int`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`.  The implementation might add custom types ot this list.